# Flex ContextMenu Change the items dynamically

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, contextmenu

I am using a ContextMenu for an AdvancedDataGrid in my application. I could implement the normal context menu for the grid. Now, I am planning to make the context menu dynamic.

For example, if I click on a particular cell, I need to see only the items related to that cell in the Context Menu. Is there any way we can do that?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found the solution for this. Quite simple:

http://www.pubbs.net/flex/200905/73331/

Comment: This is a broken link. Can this answer be expanded?

Answer (score 0):

`ContextMenu` class contains a [customItems](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html#customItems) property which is (quoting from Adobe livedocs):

> An array of ContextMenuItem objects. Each object in the array represents a context menu item that you have defined. Use this property to add, remove, or modify these custom menu items.
>
> To add new menu items, you create a ContextMenuItem object and then add it to the customItems array (for example, by using Array.push()). For more information about creating menu items, see the ContextMenuItem class entry.

Comment: Yes, I am already doing that. All I need is dynamically changing items when I am right clicking the cells.

Lets say, I have a cell with value 'Y'. If I right click, the context menu should contain, 'Change to N' and viceversa.

Any suggestions?